# Does a TreeMap's entrySet() return a TreeSet

Tags: java, collections, treemap

Does the entrySet() function that is called from a treemap instance return a TreeSet of entry's or simply a set of entry's.Is the order ensured?

Instead of getting it as a set of entry's how can a get a list of entry's in order?

Comment: Do you actually mean a `TreeSet`, or just a `Set` with certain behaviour?

Comment: I just mean't whether it would be in sorted order or not.

Comment: @Emil it looks like that the entry set returned from the set comes with a natural ordering....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the other way around: a TreeSet uses a TreeMap internally. (See first sentence of the [TreeSet docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html))

There's not much Sun java source code I can find on the web to link to, but here are some oldish versions:

- [TreeSet](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/TreeSet.java.htm)
- [TreeMap](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/TreeMap.java.htm)

As you can see, TreeMap defines an inner class called [TreeMap.EntrySet](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/Collections-Jar-Zip-Logging-regex/java/util/TreeMap.java.htm#EntrySet) which just extends AbstractSet. And no, it does not implement [SortedSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (which would otherwise probably be specified by the [SortedMap.entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet--) contract).

But to answer the actual question: yes, the order is ensured as specified in the [SortedMap.entrySet()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html#entrySet--) contract.

---

Update: JavaDoc links updated for Java 8, sources are still Java 6

Answer (score 7):

From the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#entrySet()):

> `public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet()`
>
> Returns a Set view of the mappings contained in this map. **The set's
>   iterator returns the entries in ascending key order.**

Comment: Which does not makes it a TreeSet, but rather (and I cannot consider that for granted) a SortedSet.

Comment: Right, its definetly a sorted set, but not necessarily a `java.util.SortedSet` or even a TreeSet.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert.assertFalse(new TreeMap().keySet() instanceof SortedSet );
Assert.assertFalse(new TreeMap().keySet() instanceof TreeSet ); //no need to assert
```

But the set has order actually.